# Lua global variable in module staying nil?

Tags: variables, module, lua, package, global

Im starting to learn Lua modules a bit, and I am having troubles with a small part in my Lua.
Everytime I change my variable it reverts back to nil.

myModule.lua

```
--I should note that client is a number.
module(..., package.seeall)
local LoggedIn = { }

function isLogged( client )
    return LoggedIn[client]
end

function logIn(client)
    table.insert(LoggedIn,client,true)
end

function logOut(client)
    table.remove(LoggedIn,client)
end
```

main.lua an event happens

```
package.loaded.myModule= nil; require "myModule"

function event( client )
    myModule.logIn(client)
end

function event_2( client )
    myModule.logOut(client)
end
```

**EDIT: Using functions instead, and making it local variable.
It is still returning nil even though I can confirm the logIn function happened with no errors. Without even using the logout function yet.
Any thoughts?**

but later on in main.lua I check if client is logged in and it just returns nil.

Is this just a limitation of modules or am I just accessing the variable wrong.

I should note I need to be able to do this in other Luas that acces myModule.lua too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Lua are you using? What is the value of `client`? Show us the code that uses `function event` (note that function is spelled incorrectly in your example).

Answer (score 1):

You don't really give us enough code to fully help you, but this is a working example I set up based on what little example you gave us:

```
-- myModule.lua
module(..., package.seeall)

LoggedIn = {}

function isLoggedIn(client)
    return LoggedIn[client] ~= nil
end

function LogIn(client)
    LoggedIn[client] = true
end

function LogOut(client)
    LoggedIn[client] = nil
end
```

and to test it:

```
-- main.lua
require "myModule"

myModule.LogIn("Joe")
myModule.LogIn("Frank")

print(myModule.isLoggedIn("Bill"))
print(myModule.isLoggedIn("Frank"))

myModule.LogOut("Joe")
print(myModule.isLoggedIn("Joe"))
```

this prints out as expected:

```
false
true
false
```

so my guess is that you are not checking the conditions correctly for LoggedIn[client] being empty, or you never actually remove entries from the LoggedIn table when someone 'logs out'.

Comment: Im sorry for not having more of the files but they are both nearly 700 lines long, and they have functions that are from a game.
I guess what I really wanted to know is that the global variables could be changed (and they stay that way until the module is unloaded) from outside the module.

Comment: yes, you can directly fiddle with myModule.LoggedIn unless you declare it local inside of myModule (which I would recommend). it would be safer and more clear if you made LogIn/Out functions that interacted with the LoggedIn table rather than letting any other lua file that requires myModule do that.

Answer (score 1):

The following using your own code (assuming you fix typo in `funtion`) works (it prints `true\nnil`):

```
package.loaded.myModule= nil; require "myModule"
function event( client )
    myModule.LoggedIn[client] = true
end

event("foo")
print(myModule.isLogged("foo"))
```

A better way to do this would be to add a function `logIn` as @Mike suggested and avoid using module(); you can use something like this instead:

```
local myModule = require "myModule"
function event( client )
    myModule.logIn(client)
end

event("foo")
print(myModule.isLogged("foo"))
print(myModule.isLogged("bar"))
```

And `myModule.lua` becomes:

```
local LoggedIn = { }
function isLogged( client )
  return LoggedIn[client]
end
function logIn( client )
  LoggedIn[client] = true
end
return { LoggedIn = LoggedIn, isLogged = isLogged, logIn = logIn }
```